# Using Laravel what is the correct way to store menu item's phrases?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am trying to use languages with Laravel 5.3.

I have a menu named `gender` that shows the user two options "i.e 'Male' and 'Female'".

I want to add the phrases 'Male' and 'Female' to the language file.

What is the correct way to store menu item's translation with Laravel?

I did the following

```
'gender_male' => 'Male',
'gender_female' => 'Female'
```

But then notices that that Laravel has "what I believe it to be" nested phrases. Here is an example from the code that is shipped with the Framework

```
'same'                 => 'The :attribute and :other must match.',
'size'                 => [
    'numeric' => 'The :attribute must be :size.',
    'file'    => 'The :attribute must be :size kilobytes.',
    'string'  => 'The :attribute must be :size characters.',
    'array'   => 'The :attribute must contain :size items.',
],
```

Should my language file then look like this instead? and if so how to I access I read it?

```
'gender' => [
    'male' => 'Male',
    'female' => 'Female'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the documentation for [Localization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/localization)?

All your questions should be answered there, the Laravel documentation is one of the best I know.

Comment: I have actually. but it does not talk about nesting. In fact, I don't see not even one example about nesting

Comment: I think it should work either way. Try nesting the array and then accessing it in the view via `trans('nested.property.gender.male/female')`

Answer (score 0):

I never saw second way in projects. I've just looked into source code and I'm not even sure if you'll be able to get nested translations using standard `trans()` helper.

Usually language files look like this:

```
'gender-male' => 'Male',
'gender-female' => 'Female',
```